# Counting days in month in R

Tags: r

I have data frame in R like this..

```
cambridgeparking <- read.csv("camparking.csv")

Ticket.Issue.Date   Issue.Time   Location      Violation.Description
January 1, 2014     1:24AM       Green ST      NO PARKING
January 2, 2014     10:45AM      Gore ST       NO STOPPING
January 6, 2014     3:00PM       Franklin ST   HANDICAP RAMP
..                  ..           ..            ..
March 9, 2014       3:29AM       Green ST      NO PARKING
..                  ..           ..            ..
November 10, 2014   9:30PM       Marshall ST   METER PASSED
November 30, 2014   10:20PM      Erie ST       METER PASSED
```

How do I count every violation occurred on a monthly period, so that 
It would show me total number of violations in each month?

I have tried to count it by using

```
janparking <- subset(camparking, Ticket.Issue.Date=="January 1, 2014")
```

however, it only counts violations occurred during January 1, 2014.

Comment: If you will do continuous work with date and time I suggest that you take a look at the `lubridate` package. It is very good to handle these type of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can extract the month from the 'Ticket.Issue.Date' by removing part of the substring after the month with `sub` and then use `table` to get the count per month.

```
table(sub(' .*', '', camparking$Ticket.Issue.Date))

# January    March November 
#   3        1        2
```

If we need only for 'January'

```
sum(sub(' .*', '', camparking$Ticket.Issue.Date)=='January')
#[1] 3
```

#### data

```
camparking <- structure(list(Ticket.Issue.Date = c("January 1, 2014", 
"January 2, 2014", 
"January 6, 2014", "March 9, 2014", "November 10, 2014", 
"November 30, 2014"
), Issue.Time = c("1:24AM", "10:45AM", "3:00PM", "3:29AM", "9:30PM", 
"10:20PM"), Location = c("Green ST", "Gore ST", "Franklin ST", 
"Green ST", "Marshall ST", "Erie ST"), Violation.Description = c("NO PARKING", 
"NO STOPPING", "HANDICAP RAMP", "NO PARKING", "METER PASSED", 
"METER PASSED")), .Names = c("Ticket.Issue.Date", "Issue.Time", 
"Location", "Violation.Description"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: It worked!! Is there an way for me to extract the total count for individual months (ex. January, Feburary, March, April, and so on) and print the result?

Comment: @MichaelCKang  The first option with `table` gets you all the individual months count.